# scikit learn models deploy in tensorflow serving

Tags: tensorflow, scikit-learn

I have built scikit learn models and these are ready for deployments.
would like to go with tensorflow for Deployment, gone through below link.

https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-deploy-machine-learning-models-with-tensorflow-part-1-make-your-model-ready-for-serving-776a14ec3198

can i use scikit-learn script to train and store the model in respective tensor flow directory and start use for inference.
please advise me whether scikit learn models can be served in tensorflow or not.

tried with FLASK API to expose as restful service, as we have almost 100's of models and could not go with FLASK due scaling issue.

want to go with check point like below.

```
def create_checkpoints_dir():
    '''
    Creates the checkpoints directory if it does not exist
    '''
    if not os.path.exists(checkpoints_dir):
        os.makedirs(checkpoints_dir)
```

As of now.. struck with approach itself, didn't get the results.

Comment: I overheard that you can not serve sklearn at TF-serving. Not sure what challenge you are having with Flask. Another option would be move your model to Google Cloud or other cloud providers have services build-in